# iOS Swift: Sort array into three dimensional array

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have an array of CKRecords that I would like to sort into a three dimensional array. Within the first array is an array of dates, and each date is an array of names, where a name is an Int between 0 and 4. I'm successfully sorting my records into a two dimensional array currently (code below).

Name can be retrieved with `record.objectForKey("Name") as Int`

```
func buildIndex(records: [CKRecord]) -> [[CKRecord]] {
    var dates = [NSDate]()
    var result = [[[CKRecord]]]()

    for record in records {
        var date = record.objectForKey("startTime") as NSDate

        if !contains(dates, date) {
            dates.append(date)
        }
    }

    for date in dates {
        var recordForDate = [CKRecord]()

        for (index, exercise) in enumerate(records) {
            let created = exercise.objectForKey("startTime") as NSDate

            if date == created {
                let record = records[index] as CKRecord
                recordForDate.append(record)
            }
        }
        result.append(recordForDate)
    }

    return result
}
```

Not sure the best way to approach this problem. Even general guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

General Overview:

**Step 1** - choose your sort algorithm. I find that the [insertion sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is the easiest for me to understand and is fast too.

**Step 2** - decide on your data structure. You could use a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension represents your dates, and the second dimension represents your records. So the array might be defined like this `List<List<CKRecord>>`. So the first entry would contain a list (`List<CKRecord>`) of all the records with the earliest date (it may be one or many).

**Basic Steps**

*(with a 2-D array)*

1. So start with the empty data structure
2. Figure out which Date list it should go into
3. If the date does not exist yet, you need to *sort* the date into the correct position and add a new array/list with the new entry as the only contents
4. If the date already exists, you need to *sort* the record into the correct position of the already existing list of records
5. *Enjoy*

Comment: Thanks for the overview. I haven't used two dimensional arrays before. If you have any code samples that would be very appreciated :)